# how to differentiate the following w.r.t t $s= s(t) = 4e^{3t} +2.5e^{-2.5t}$

Tags: calculus

How do I find $\frac{ds}{dt}$?

$$s= s(t) = 4e^{3t} +2.5e^{-2.5t}$$

Hi guys im battling here, please help

Answer (score 1):

$$s= s(t) = 4e^{3t} +2.5e^{-2.5t}$$

Note that in general $\frac{d}{dt} e^{g(t)}= g'(t)e^{g(t)}$ where $g(t)$ is some function of $t$

Then $$\frac{ds}{dt} = 4\cdot 3e^{3t} +2.5\cdot-2.5\cdot e^{-2.5t}$$

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 12e^{3t} -6.25e^{-2.5t}$$

Comment: much appreciated @mrnovicehttp://math.stackexchange.com/users/416020/mrnovice

Comment: when i worked it out i came to =12eˆ3t + 2.5eˆ-2.5t     where am i getting it wrong

Comment: @k.adank You subtracted instead  multiplying your second term by the differential of its exponent which is $-2.5$, so you should have gotten $-2.5\cdot 2.5\cdot e^{-2.5t}$

Answer (score 0):

If we have any exponential term not in product with any other term, then we have to first differentiate it and then derivative of power.

Let $s = 4e^{3t}$

$\frac {ds}{dt} = 4 \cdot \frac{d}{dt} e^{3t}$

$\frac {ds}{dt} = 4 \cdot e^{3t} \cdot \frac d{dt}3t$

$\frac {ds}{dt} = 4 \cdot e^{3t} \cdot 3$

Similarly you can find for other term.

Comment: If any doubt please ask.

Comment: Great guys. could you help with the following, i will be writing exams on this stuff next week.

Comment: Differentiate the following:
y = 4 sin2 θ - 3 cos4θ w.r.t θ

Integrate the following expressions:

∫(5sin2θ+2cos4θ)dθ

and

∫(2xˆ3 -3xˆ2 +5x-2)dx

Help very much appreciated

Comment: You just need to memorize differentiation and integration formulas. Then above questions easy for you. For example if $y = 4\sin\theta$ then keep 4 aside and differentiate you get $\frac{dy}{d\theta}=4 \cos2\theta . 2$ Similarly find derivative of $3\cos 4\theta$